# PHP stripping strings

Tags: php, string, strip

I would like to strip everything in a string before a - and leave what's after that. For example:

15.11-101

I want to strip 15.11 and leave 101. I've tried a few different things, but can't seem to get it working, if anyone could help me out, that'd be fantastic :)

Cheers

Leanne

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$result = substr($original, strpos($original, '-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming it appears only once, you can use the [explode](http://php.net/explode) function.

```
$s='15.11-101';
$a=explode('-',$s,1);
echo $a[1];
```

This should be the fastest way.